# How to Determine if 2 Circles Overlap

Tags: java

So I'm creating a class and have to determine if two circles are overlapping based on their distance. This is what I have:

```
    Circle a = other;
    Circle b = other;

    double xDist = a.getX() - a.getX();
    double yDist = b.getY() - b.getY();

    double radi = a.getRadius() + b.getRadius();

    double distance = Math.sqrt((xDist*xDist) + (yDist*yDist));

    if((distance  < radi * radi)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

My process is that if the distance of the centers is less than the sum of their radii, then the circles overlap.

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but you might be able to make use of [Eclipse2D's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) functionalities for checking intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you're trying to compare the distance with the *square* of the sum of the radii.  You want to compare the distance with the sum of the radii.

Alternatively,  you could compare the *square* of the distance to the *square* of the sum of the radii, which would remove the need to use `Math.sqrt`.

Note also that there's no point in having variables `a` and `b`, when you've already got `this` and `other` to refer to the two discs.  In fact, you've incorrectly made `a` and `b` both refer to `other`.  You could fix this as follows.

```
public boolean overlaps(Disk other) {
    double xDistance = getX() - other.getX();
    double yDistance = getY() - other.getY();

    double sumOfRadii = getRadius() + other.getRadius();
    double distanceSquared = xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance;

    boolean isOverlapping = distanceSquared  < sumOfRadii * sumOfRadii;
    return isOverlapping;
}
```

Comment: Might also want to point out that `a` and `b` are the same `Disk other`

Comment: Shouldn't it be distanceSquared  <= sumOfRadii * sumOfRadii; ?

Answer (score 2):

Change 2 things:

```
Circle a = this; // "this" instead of "other"
```

and remove the call to `Math.sqrt()`